# MongoDB query dbpath value

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to get the value of dbpath of a running MongoDB instance via query, assuming I am connected as an admin? Unsurprisingly, it does not appear in the result of [db.serverStatus](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/#db.serverStatus) command output.

Comment: I assume you are talking of [`dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath)? I am not aware of a method to access it, but may be you can elaborate your use case a bit, so that we can find a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found that it is actually pretty easy:

```
db._adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

gives you both `argv` and the parsed options that differ from the defaults, as far as I can see. You can access the `dbpath` variable via

```
db._adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.storage.dbPath
```

regardless of where `dbpath` is defined **if** it differs from the defaults for your OS, which you most likely have to hard code according to the [documentation of the `dbpath` config variable](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath).

Comment: Great find! I knew that the path is located in mongod.conf file, but I could not access it. Good to know that there's a parsed version of it available